# Newsfeed problem

Tags: site-collection, newsfeed

I created a new site collection and when I click on the newsfeed link it goes to the newsfeed of another site collection. How should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean the Newsfeed link in the header? Or in Current Navigation?

Comment: I mean the header's one, but not Newsfeed only, even OneDrive and Sites

Answer (score 1):

That header link will usually always go to the My Site host where the Newsfeed is hosted. You can also enable 'Site feeds' feature on a Web. This will provision the Newsfeed at a Web level which can be embedded on a page as a web part or should provision a page at {Web URL}/Newsfeed.aspx.

Posting to this Web level Newsfeed will show on the My Site host newsfeed as a Post from the Web where the post originated.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your environment is SP2013 on-premise. To be honest, I cannot see any problem on it based on your description. Typically, Newsfeed and OneDrive are configured as another site collections per user. If the links for newsfeed does not work, I suspect it would be user profile service application issue, more specifically My Site setting. If I not, please provide me with URLs of site collections.